# mongodb Calculate distance from coordinates from 5400 documents

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, gps

I have a collection with 5400 documents. I kept data from 1 player during a soccer game. Every second i get the long and lat from the player. Now I want the total distance of the player during the game.

Some idea's ?

This is an example of one document:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59807a01702661033d918e8e"),
    "playerId" : 1,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-01T11:11:45.078Z")
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            4.94193, 
            51.32447
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: See [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/). It orders by "nearest" and projects the distance from the queried location. If you want distance from a queried point for more than 100 documents ( default return) then you would need to increase the `"limit"` option to cater for your collection size or expected result size, whichever you actually intend. Usually we don't care about a very large selection of results and are simply interested in the "nearest". Hence the reasonable default.

Comment: I looked already for $geonear but I have no idea how to use it. Is it possible to give an example ?

Comment: You mean and example like the examples listed on the documentation page, which is actually linked in the comment given above? If you "already looked" then you should have seem the example usage demonstrated in the documentation. That is what it is there for.

Comment: Sorry for my English but it's not my native language. I have written this piece of code, but I get the 28 coordinates that are closest to that point, but I want the distance between coordinates 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, ... 5399 and 5400. 

`db.playerTrackings_copy.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 4.931326 , 51.3210 ] },
        distanceField: "dist",
        spherical: true,
        limit: 28
    }},
    {$sort: {dist :-1}}
])`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all of the points of the player, calculate the distances between them, and sum the distances up.
For the distance calculation, you can use this algorithm(using php, hope that it's fine)

```
class Geo
{
    const R = 6371000;

    /**
     * @param float[] $point1 latitude and longitude
     * @param float[] $point2  latitude and longitude
     * @return float
     */
    static public function calculateDistance($point1, $point2)
    {
        $latRad1 = deg2rad($point1[0]);
        $latRad2 = deg2rad($point2[0]);
        $deltaLat = deg2rad($point2[0] - $point1[0]);
        $deltaLon = deg2rad($point2[1] - $point1[1]);

        $a = sin($deltaLat/2) * sin($deltaLat/2) +
            cos($latRad1) * cos($latRad2) *
            sin($deltaLon/2) * sin($deltaLon/2);
        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));

        return self::R * $c;
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpfull.